# Cake 3 Blog Tutorial Error While using newEntity

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

here is the error happened :
`Unable to find table class for current entity`

here is add method of Articles Controller

```
public function add()
{
    $article = $this->Articles->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Articles->save($article)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
    }
    $this->set('article', $article);
}
```

And Here is add.ctp

```
<h1>Add Article</h1>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create($article);
    echo $this->Form->input('title');
    echo $this->Form->input('body', ['rows' => '3']);
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Save Article'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was because of Entity ! , i jsut created a Entity file like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * User Entity.
 */
class Article extends Entity
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your installation of CakePHP 3. What you are experiencing was a bug that appeared early after releasing the first Releseas Candidate. To update your installation run:

```
composer update
```

In the root directory of your app where the composer.json file is.

Comment: Oops ! , not Fixed :|

Comment: Are you sure it was updated? Try looking up your composer.json an share it here using gist.github.com, also share your composer.lock file